# How to tell if a Chrome extension is installed by a real user vs. by me during development?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using Analytics in my Chrome extension. I want to execute the analytics code only if the extension is being used by a real person (not me while I'm working on it). Are any of the following doable and which is the best?

1. Identify whether the extension was installed packed or unpacked. I think this is the best because unpacked clearly means it's "in development" and it's not specific to my machine in any way. Can the extension know this programatically?
2. Have the extension look for something that's specific to my environment. I'm not sure what that something is (extension is open-source so it can't be anything too private).
3. Have a "developer mode" option on the options page. Doable but that means anyone who installs the extension can just turn it on.
4. Set a localStorage variable manually and never erase it. Doable but not the best solution because if it ever disappears, I'd have to reset it. And I have to remember not to delete it if I ever delete keys from localStorage.
5. `var useAnalytics = false` while developing, set it to true before releasing. It's not automatic but its an option.
6. Something else?

Comment: istead of making it complex. Can't you just have the analytics code in a seperate empty JS file and then add the analytics code just before releasing. Test it one final time after the JS update.

Comment: I want to do things like track clicks on various buttons within my extension. If I have to manually remove analytics every time I'm developing, I'd have to remove all of those statements too. I'd say the easiest "manual" way would be to set a variable somewhere called useAnalytics and set that to false while I develop and then set it to true when I release. I'd still prefer something automatic though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your production extension will have a single `extension_id` that will not change while your unpacked extension will have a random `extension_id` that will change if you remove and load it again. You can use the [il8n API](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/i18n.html#method-getMessage) to get the `extension_id` check if it matches the production `extension_id`.

`var extensionId = chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@extension_id');`

Comment: That works, though it's weird that you get the extension id through the i18n API. Thanks.

Comment: The `@@extension_id` is designed for CSS files so you can use different images based on language. It just works nicely for this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Google Analytics opt-out
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fllaojicojecljbmefodhfapmkghcbnh?hl=en