# Handling with URLs across production & dev environments

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have built a small extension where I had to hard-code URLs in many places(like manifest.json, etc). But I want the domain of the URLs differ between dev & production environment. Wondering what is the right practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you can know your production extension url then you can see the extension id. Suppose the extension url is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eme-call-and-event-logger/cniohcjecdcdhgmlofniddfoeokbpbpb so the `var chromeruntimeid='cniohcjecdcdhgmlofniddfoeokbpbpb';`

```
  if(chrome.runtime.id==chromeruntimeid){
    console.log('production');
  }else{
    console.log('development');
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try creating a JSON file and have different key, value pairs in it in the following manner:

```
"development": {
    "oauth-code": "xyz"
}

"production": {
    "oauth-code": "xyz"
}
```

and then load settings.json into your main script and access the setting dynamically depending upon the environment that you've chosen in the following manner:

```
var settings = [code to load JSON file, depending upon the language that you choose]
console.log(settings['production'].oauth-code);
console.log(settings['development'].oauth-code);
```

It will help you to get custom settings depending upon the environment more easily, you can though also try using an application object in your JS file with the same properties, its almost the same manner, though it is advisable to seperate settings and main logic from each other.

Comment: Thanks Cody. But how do I access the settings in manifest.json?

Comment: You have to use the code specific to your development language, to load the JSON file, which will return you the JSON object.

Comment: We need to upload the manifest.json to chrome store. They will parse the json file themselves to understand the details of the chrome extension package.

Comment: Here is a better solution not requiring to split the code base in any way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034702/how-to-tell-if-a-chrome-extension-is-installed-by-a-real-user-vs-by-me-during-d